# how exit from a method which of not void type?

Tags: java

Is there any way to exit a from a method(which is not a void type) call and return control to main method in order execute rest of code.

```
public class main
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int a,b;
--------------
-------------
check(a,b);
-----------
----------
}
}
public static int check (int x ,int y)
{---------------
----------------
if(some_condition)
{//should exit from current method and return control to main.
}
-------------
-------------
return c; 
}
}
```

Comment: returning a value should do the trick. or you can throw an exception, but I wouldn't do that

Comment: Yeah, you can use the `return` statement pretty much anywhere inside the `check` method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it depends on the situation and what you want to achieve.
If you ignore the return value anyway (as in the example code you provided), then you could just return a hardcoded value.
If you use the value returned by the method, then there is two options:

1. returning a hardcoded value, then in the main method check for this value (if the hardcoded is returned ignore it, use it otherwise);
2. throw an exception, then catch it in the main method.

Comment: throwing an exception seems a right way, as in my I am using that method returned  value all  around the program.so returning any value will affect the whole program and I will have to make change whole program.

Comment: @YogeshSatyam throwing an exception will affect it just as much, if not more. Exceptions should be thrown if an Unexpected occassion occurs. does 'condition' point to something unexpected?

Comment: yeah ,like invalid inputs(eg:values 0 in case division)